# Why can't I find the substring in a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to find whether a sub-string is present in a string, without using any library functions. I know that its very simple and i have done this before in C,C++ and Java. But, I am not getting output in JavaScript. I use the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var j,i;
        var str=window.prompt("Enter the string: ");
        var substr=window.prompt("Enter the string to be searched: ");
        var len=str.length;
        var sublen=substr.length;
        j=0,i=0; 
        whlie(i<len)
        {
            if(str[i]==substr[j])
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        if(j==sublen)
        {
            document.write("Substring found");
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("Substring not found");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Can anyone please tell me, whats wrong with this code.? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why don't you just use indexOf or match instead of implementing it yourself?

Comment: Seems like you are comparing characters ..

Comment: Because this is for exam purpose. We cannot use library functions in exams.

Comment: @user2923116 But it isn't a library...

Comment: If you don't get outputs, it's usually because of syntax error. The parsing of the script will stop at the point where the error occurs (Some browsers will warn you about it).

Comment: i cant use this function because if i use this function, there is nothing to do for me.

Comment: I have tried it all and i think the problem with the code is that the control doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: If this is for an exam, isn't asking for help here as bad, if not worse than using a library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. `whlie(i<len)` should be `while(i<len)`.

Also, there are easier ways to do it, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't understand.

Comment: In the 10th line of your code, change `whlie` to `while` and your code will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `indexOf()` function

```
var str=window.prompt("Enter the string: ");
var substr=window.prompt("Enter the string to be searched: ");
if( str.indexOf(substr) > -1 ){
    document.write("Substring found");
}
else{
    document.write("Substring not found");
}
```

---

If you want to do it in **while loop** instead of using `indexOf()` ... try this

```
var found = false;
i = 0;
while( i < str.length - substr.length + 1 )
{
    if(str[i]==substr[0])
    {
        j = 0;
        found = true;
        while( j < substr.length ){
            if( str[i+j] != substr[j] ){
                found = false;
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    if( found == true ) break;
    i++;
}

if( found == true ){
    document.write("Substring found");
}
else{
    document.write("Substring not found");
}
```

---

Compact **for loop** version

```
var found = false;      
for( i=0; i < str.length - substr.length + 1 ; i++){
    if( str[i] == substr[0] )
        for( j=0, found=true; j < substr.length; j++)
            if( str[i+j] != substr[j] ){
                found = false;
                break;
            }
    if( found ) break;
}
```

**EDIT:**  `- substr.length + 1` is added in outer loops of both versions.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the incorrect spelling of `while`, your implementation is logically incorrect because once there is a partial match it begins the next match from the point where it left.

Suppose str = "RAVING_RAVEN_RISES"
and     substr = "RAVEN"

Now in your code iteration proceeds as follows :

- i = 0, j = 0
- i = 1, j = 1 (R matches with R)
- i = 2, j = 2 (A matches with A)
- i = 3, j = 3 (V matches with V)
- i = 4, j = 3 (I doesn't match with E)

...

You don't decrement j anywhere so when i = 7, it doesn't attempt matching with R as it should but rather attempts matching with E which causes it to fail.

While [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is a much simple solution (no external dependencies), if the intent of exam is to check your understanding of algorithms, instead of implementing a  naive algorithm, I'd recommend you to check out [Knuth Morris Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) String matching algorithm. A javascript implementation of the same is as follows :

```
function kmp_search(s, w) {
      var m = 0, i = 0, 
          pos, cnd, t,
          slen = s.length,
          wlen = w.length;

      /* String to array conversion */
      s = s.split("");
      w = w.split("");    

      /* Construct the lookup table */
      t = [-1, 0];
      for ( pos = 2, cnd = 0; pos  0 )
            cnd = t[cnd];
          else 
            t[pos++] = 0;
      } 

      /* Perform the search */
      while ( m + i  -1 ) 
                  i = t[i];
              else
                  i = 0;
          }
      }
      return -1;
  }
```

Ref: http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_Algorithm_Examples#Javascript

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
whlie(i<len) it will be while(i < len)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this quite easily with a regex. No additional library needed.

```
var str = window.prompt("Enter the string: "),
  substr = window.prompt("Enter the string to be searched: "),
  substrR = new RegExp(substr);

if (substrR.test(str)) {
  document.write("Substring found");
} 
else {
  document.write("Substring not found");
}
```

Comment: -1 for regex. Why do you need to weigh it down with regex?

Comment: Mostly because it was the first thing I thought of. I'm guessing the 'i' flag could prove useful too

Comment: You could emulate the i flag by .toLower()ing.